# Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FC'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a new react application by running

```
npx create-react-app myApp --typescript
```

I also updated `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` to the latest versions, however, this error still persists when I try to declare a component's type like so

```
export const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return <div />;
};
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to add at the top: `import * as React from "react";`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Executing `npx create-react-app myApp --typescript` fails with error: _"Cannot create a project named 'myApp' because of npm naming restrictions: * name can no longer contain capital letters Please choose a different project name. "_ So I re-executed it changing 'myApp' to 'myapp', then added your code to `myapp\src\App.tsx` and ran `yarn build`. It compiles and builds fine. I'd suggest you do the same.

Comment: It still does not work. I have also tried with React.FunctionComponent

Comment: Which React version are you using `React.FC` is only available since 16.8

Comment: Just tangential, but you should consider not using React.FC. 
 Short version: no benefit, some small downsides, long version - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Comment: add types `npm i  --save-dev @types/react @types/react-dom`

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new sanbox with typescript. https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-nobel-phcd7 . Try to compare its settings with your project. You can even download it as a zip file and start a new project from it.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Update**

I downloaded the zip file. It works for me. All I can think of is the globally installed npm versions.

You can check them with:

`npm list -g --depth 0`

I do not know my version hels you, but it works for me wit theese:

```
├── create-react-app@3.3.1
├── firebase-tools@7.6.1
├── ionic@5.4.6
├── nlf@1.4.3
├── npm@6.13.7
├── nsp@2.8.0
├── ts-node@8.0.3
└── typescript@3.3.3333
```

Comment: Works on the sandbox, but inexplicably won't work even after downloading and running npm install!

Comment: It is really strange. I updated my answer. You should check node version as well. I have no better idea.

Comment: React.Component? I've never used React.FC before, but the error seems to be that there is no FC exported from React. With the create-react-app package I've only seen React.Component.

Comment: @SydneyY React.FC is the typescript type of Functional Component. Try out Typescript sometimes if you create a bigger project.

Comment: Cool to know, I'm just starting my first ts project, although it uses Angular. My point, though, is: is FC available in this package? I'm still checking on that myself.

Comment: I've confirmed for myself that FC exists. But the docs for create-react-app point out that if you have ever installed their package globally you'll have to uninstall that. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new project using this command

```
npx create-react-app myapp --typescript
```

(first of you can't use any capital letter in a project name)

And tried to create component type like this and its work for me fine No error display

```
export const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return <div />;
};
```

Maybe your package.json file having some versioning issue 
My package.json file look's like this

```
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my App.jsx file looks like

```
import React from "react"
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`React.FC` work for me perfectly

Answer (score 1):

React.FC was removed from create-react-app CRA, see: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Answer (score 0):

The docs for create-react-app point out that if you have ever installed their package globally you'll have to uninstall that. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript

This may be preventing your app from reading the correct configuration on create-react-app. The global version you have may be js and the local ts, then if the global create-react-app script is run it doesn't transpile the ts.